# T-SQL: match color to result value range?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure how to explain, so here goes.

We need to match a range of values to a color. We have four colors: *red*, *orange*, *yellow*, *green*.

Today we ran the query and this is the result:

```
declare @difference decimal (4,2)
declare @products table
(
    ItemPrice money
)
insert into @products
select 4.47 union
select 4.21 union
select 4.82 union
select 4.30 union
select 4.75 union
select 4.81 union
select 4.61 union
select 4.70 union
select 4.62 union
select 4.10 union
select 4.52 union
select 4.30 union
select 4.27 

select 
@difference = (max(itemprice)-min(ItemPrice))/4 from @products
select @difference

select itemprice,
case 
when itemprice >= 4.10 and itemprice <= (4.10+@difference) then 'red'
when itemprice >= 4.10+@difference and itemprice <= (4.28+@difference) then 'orange'
when itemprice >= 4.28+@difference and itemprice <= (4.46+@difference) then 'yellow'
when itemprice >= 4.46+@difference and itemprice <= (4.64+@difference) then 'yellow'
end
from @products
```

How can I do this without having to specify the values in the `case` statement?

Comment: CASE WHEN something BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN dark green WHEN something BETWEEN 5 AND 7 THEN green ... if you create an actual [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle) with sample data and desired results, you'll likely get better answers than a word problem.

Comment: You can use [NTILE(6)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to rank the values into six groups and map that value to a color

Comment: NTILE doesn't do it because there might be huge gaps in the list. I.e., the first 2 empids had 5 orders, the third one had 398520 orders.  NTILE would assign 2 to the third empid. It should be 6.

Comment: Maybe it’s because I didn’t have six distinct values in my test set

Comment: Yup, [I was correct](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36935f115eacd4fdde632cea299b0b99). When there are 5 distinct values, the highest one is given 5, no matter how high it is.

Comment: @RossPresser If you only have 5 values, you need to leave one color out. Why does it matter if the outlier is really big or really small? (And I'm not saying NTILE is the answer, e.g. if the data is really skewed but they still want the color bands represented by absolute and identical sets of values as opposed to relative). I still think a real example with real sample data and real desired results and real edge cases like skew will go a lot further than the original word problem and will be more useful than us guessing and stabbing.

Comment: I am guessing the assigned color indicates how extreme the order count is. Give it the wrong color and it might get assigned to the wrong group of support people or something.  You're right about a real sample being needed here.

Comment: @RossPresser About extreme: yes. But if you have 1,10,100,1000,50000, which one is most extreme at which end and why? We have no idea. And if you do have an extreme case (again, at either end) and you just divide up by (max-min)/6, everything else is going to go into the one bucket at the other end (50000 - 100)/6 = 4 of those 5 values in bucket 1.

Comment: Aside: Although the result is predictable, it's a bit odd to construct a `case` _expression_ so that multiple conditions are met, e.g. `1 <= Foo and Foo <= 10` and `10 <= Foo and Foo <= 100`. Changing one of the conditions from `<=` to `<` makes the intent clear, e.g. `1 <= Foo and Foo < 10`.

Comment: @HABO to be fair, a result on the boundary will only fall into the first CASE condition it meets (but in general, yes, I do agree it should be expressed so there is no ambiguity).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Oh, is that what "predictable" means?

Comment: @HABO yes, I don't think we're debating or misunderstanding the definition of predictable. However other readers might not know what you mean.

Comment: Is one of the `'yellow'` results supposed to be `'green'`?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you actually want an open-ended range, e.g. `4.28` should only be valid for one color, regardless of how the `CASE` expression is ordered. Also, presumably, the 4th condition was meant to be some other color than `yellow`.

```
declare @diff decimal (4,2), @min decimal(4,2);

select @min  = min(ItemPrice),
       @diff = (max(itemprice)-min(ItemPrice))/4 from @products

select ItemPrice, case        when ItemPrice < @min+@diff*1 then 'red'
when ItemPrice >= @min+@diff*1 AND ItemPrice < @min+@diff*2 then 'orange'
when ItemPrice >= @min+@diff*2 AND ItemPrice < @min+@diff*3 then 'yellow'
when itemprice >= @min+@diff*3 then 'some other color' end
from @products;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a36658987582b7b92e6323aec6d6a87b)